# how to deploy static subdomain + wildcard subdomain laravel app on live server?

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

In my laravel project app, I have the following routes. `app.client.net` for user registration and wildcard subdomain `*.client.net` for logged in users.
Route.php

```php
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::group(['domain' => 'app.client.net'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function () {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            return redirect('http://'.session('subdomain').'.client.net/home');
        }       
        return view('welcome');
    })->name('homepage');   
    Route::get('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
    Route::get('/setupCompany', 'CompanyController@setupCompanyForm')->name('setupCompanyForm');
    Route::post('/setupCompany', 'CompanyController@setupCompany')->name('setupCompany');
    Route::get('/register/verify', 'CompanyController@verfiy')->name('registerVerify');

});

Route::group(['domain'=> '{subdomain}.client.net', 'middleware' => 'checkSubdomain'],function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\CompanyLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('companyLogin');
    Route::post('/', 'Auth\CompanyLoginController@login')->name('companyLogin');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'customAuth'],function(){         
        Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
        Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
        Route::post('/inviteClient', 'HomeController@inviteClient'); //ajax req
        Route::get('/profile', ['as' => 'profile.edit', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@edit']);
        Route::put('profile', ['as' => 'profile.update', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@update']);
        Route::put('profile/password', ['as' => 'profile.password', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@password']);

        Route::get('/getClients', 'HomeController@clients'); //ajax req

    });
});
```

this is working good on localhost but when I deployed it on a live server by making `app.client.net` subdomain on server and deployed project there then wildcard subdomain `{subdomain}.client.net` is not working.
when I go to `app.client.net` it is working properly but when I go to wildcard subdomain e.g  `abc.client.net` it gives following error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

how to configure this so that static subdomain and wildcard subdomain can work on server subdomain.
Or I have to make two subdomains on server `app.client.net` and `*.client.net` separately, one is for static subdomain and other one is for wildcard subdomain and deploys static subdomain routes on `app.client.net` server subdomain and wildcard subdomain routes on `*.client.net` server wildcard subdomain separately?
Thanks in advance.